# How do i convert a date string from user input to date.today() python

Tags: python

Python newbie, i need to convert a string from a user input in the format dd/mm/yyyy and check to see if it is in the future?, will i need to re order the format of the input for comparison and convert it to a date object.

Comment: [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're specifically wanting to do, this will take in dd/mm/yyyy and tell you if it's older than now.

```
import time

# Get input
date = input("Enter a date: ")
# Convert to timestamp
date_timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y"))

# Check if in future
if(date_timestamp > time.time()):
    print("It's in the future,")
else:
    print("It's not in the future,")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.date(datetime.today())
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)

date_strings = [d.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') for d in (today, yesterday, tomorrow)]

for date_string in date_strings:
    print datetime.date(datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d/%m/%Y')) > today
```

Ouputs:

```
False
False
True
```